# For a polynomial $f\in\mathbb Z[X]$ there exists some natural number $m>2016$ such that $|f(m)|$ is not a prime number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

> $f(X) = \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i X^i$ is a polynomial with $a_i \in\mathbb Z $, $n>0$ and $a_n \neq 0$. Prove that there exists some natural number $m>2016$  such that $|f(m)|$ is not a prime number.

I need hints how to approach this, since no idea has crossed my mind. thank you

Comment: What do you think about $m = |a_{0}| \cdot 2016$?

Comment: @openspace what if $a_0 = 1$?

Comment: @openspace might not work if $a_0=0$ or 1.

Comment: @BigbearZzz if $a_0=0$, $f(m)$ is divisible by $m$.

Comment: @Wore doesn't change that fact that m = 0*2016 < 2016.

Comment: If $a_{0} = 0$ then you could take $m = 2018$ for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $|f(2017)|$ is not a prime. Then you are done, pick $m=2017$.

Otherwise, $|f(2017)|=p$ is a prime. Now, all numbers of the form $2017+kp$, with $k \ge 0$, satisfy
$$f(2017 + kp) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$
and only finitely many of them satisfy $f(2017 + kp) \in \{ 0,p,-p\}$. So, there exist some $k \ge 0$ such that $f(2017+kp)$ is a (proper) multiple of $p$. For such number $k$, $|f(2017+kp)|$ is composite.

Comment: how do you explain that only finitely many satisfy what you wrote?

Comment: Since $f$ is a polynomial, the equation $f(x)=p$ has ony finitely many solutions (it could be that there are no solution at all, but, you know, $0$ is a finite number). The same for $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=-p$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a hint under "Prime formulas and polynomial functions":

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: OP asked for hint. It's good enough to deduce some variation of your answer.